# three.js MultiMaterial opacity depth order

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm doing a squash game with three.js and I'm adding the player model loaded through a collada file.

I need the player model to be relatively transparent so that the ball and other elements can be seen even if under the object.

I iterate through all the materials of the object's `MultiMaterial` and set them transparent and with opacity value 0.7.

However, when I do this, as the model has several components, I can see the eyes, mouth, etc. as seen in this picture:

[image: Example]

Code:

```
var loader2 = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader2.load("./squash/player/wip2.dae", function(collada) {

  collada.scene.traverse(function(child) {

    if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

        for (var i = 0; i < child.material.materials.length; i++) {

            var m = child.material.materials[i];
            m.skinning = true;

            m.transparent = true;
            m.opacity = 0.7;              //here

        }

        child.material.skinning = true;

        player = child;

        player.castShadow = true;
        player.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add(player);

    }

});

});
```

Live example - http://eqstest.ruidorey.webfactional.com/tennis.html

How can I do to make the **occluded parts** of the player model to be **hidden** so I don't see the eyes, mouth, head when for example the hair is on top of them?

Comment: will you be looking at the character always from the back?

Comment: not always...but you have a suggestion when that is case?

Comment: if you are always looking from the back I would not draw the elements that I dont want.

Comment: Yes, that I thought also...and thank you. If possible I prefer to have them drawn...but that is a solution if there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to render your player twice.

In the first render of your player, for each material in your materials array, set `material.colorWrite = false;`. This will render to the depth buffer only.

Then render your player a second time as usual with `material.colorWrite = true;`

three.js r.73